# Quais ferramentas utilizar para criar games WEB?

Tags: php, html5, python, aplicação-web, canvas

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês nas seguintes questões:

**1.** Qual melhor opção para desenvolvimento de games web ?

**2.**   HTML5 com Canvas, Javascript e PHP ? O que acham dessa combinação ?

**3.**   Python é uma opção ?

Estou realmente indeciso com qual caminho seguir, levando em consideração a curva de aprendizado.

Comment: Acho que JS puro seria uma boa opção, justamente porque games têm um grande apelo gráfico. O *back-end* pode ser em qualquer linguagem, inclusive PHP e Python. Se você quer rapidez, vá pelo que conhece. Se quer aprender algo diferente e mais rico, eu diria que Python seria o ideal.

Comment: JS . Vide http://candybox2.net/ que por sinal é bem divertido.

Answer (score 1):

1. Recomendo o GameMaker studio, é muito simples e intuitívo e não é necessário programação, somente em casos específicos. tem uma interface amigavel e além de exportar para web, também da pra exportar para android, ios, windows e windows phone.
2. Caso queira fazer na "unha" os jogos, pode ser utilizado html5, js, jquery e php, é uma boa combinação. talvez até node.js possa complementar.
3. Acredito que não. Mas depende, alguns evangelistas do python diriam que sim, é muito relativo.

Comment: + 1 pela expressão "evangelistas do python".